# FirebaseUI not showing any input fields or buttons

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

I want to implement `FirebaseUI`in my project, but the login page is not showing any input fields or buttons:

[image: FUIAuth]

Code for showing `FUIAuth`:

```
@IBAction func logInButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {

        let authUI = FUIAuth.defaultAuthUI()

        guard authUI != nil else {
            //Log error

            return
        }

        authUI?.delegate = self
        authUI?.providers = [FUIEmailAuth]()

        let authViewController = authUI!.authViewController()

        present(authViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }

}

extension LogInViewController: FUIAuthDelegate {

    func authUI(_ authUI: FUIAuth, didSignInWith authDataResult: AuthDataResult?, error: Error?) {

        if error != nil {

            return
        }

        performSegue(withIdentifier: "ToHomeVCSegue", sender: self)
    }
 }
```

I have tried lots of different options in the podfile:

```
pod 'Firebase/Core'
pod 'Firebase/Auth'
pod 'Firebase/Database'
pod 'FirebaseUI'
pod 'FirebaseUI/Email'
```

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into this same issue and it seems that all of the examples out there are missing some aspect of the steps required to make the providers appear.  The first answer was correct but didnt give examples.  In the code below I am just suing email and Google auth.  This code is embedded in a login button pressed event.

```
let authUI = FUIAuth.defaultAuthUI()
        
guard authUI != nil else {
    print("authUI error")
    return
}
authUI?.delegate = self
let providers: [FUIAuthProvider] = [
    FUIEmailAuth(),
    FUIGoogleAuth()
]
authUI?.providers = providers
let authViewController = authUI!.authViewController()
present(authViewController, animated: true)
```

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully it's not too late. But the problem looks to be with this line of code here

```
        authUI?.providers = [FUIEmailAuth]()
```

The '.providers' property requires an array of type FUIAuthProviders.

Your code is basically trying to pass an array of type FUIEmailAuth, which the '.providers' property doesn't understand.

Here's an example of initializing an array of type FUIAuthProviders

```
        let authProviders: [FUIAuthProviders] = []
```